# Select a single item in html parse list. HTML AglilityPack

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I would like to be able to be able to select each item is an individual list. look at this HTML:

```
<div class="services"> 
<a class="service selected" onclick="serviceNameClick('');" href="#">all</a>    
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('12');" href="#">12</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('14');" href="#">14</a>  
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('14C');" href="#">14C</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('N14');" href="#">N14</a>
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('14B');" href="#">14B</a>     
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('27');" href="#">27</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('12A');" href="#">12A</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('27C');" href="#">27C</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('N12');" href="#">N12</a> 
<a class="service" onclick="serviceNameClick('14A');" href="#">14A</a>  
</div>
```

To be able to display this as a list like:
all 12 14 N14 14B 27 12A 27 N12 14A

I am able to get there using the code below:

```
    string htmlPage = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://m.buses.co.uk/stop.aspx?stopid=" + stopIdVariable);


        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

        List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();
        foreach (var a in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'content')]"))
        {

            Movie newMovie = new Movie();
            //newMovie.Cover = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='image']//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
           // newMovie.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h4[@itemprop='name']").InnerText.Trim();
          //  newMovie.Summary = div.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='outline']").InnerText.Trim();
            newMovie.Summary = a.SelectSingleNode("div[starts-with(@class, 'service')]").InnerText.Trim();
            movies.Add(newMovie);


        }lstMovies.ItemsSource = movies;
```

This displays it in a list, but I am unable to select individual items on that result,

It makes me select it all as a list and not as each one.

Also the aim to be able to select that and then use that value as a text field. So user clicks on 12 and then I use that 12 within the app.

What needs to be change? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                        .SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'content')]//a[@class='service']")
foreach (var a in links)
{
    Movie newMovie = new Movie();
    newMovie.Summary = a.InnerText.Trim();
    movies.Add(newMovie);
}
lstMovies.ItemsSource = movies;
```

Basically, the XPath passed as argument of `SelectNodes()` above select individual `<a>` nodes having class equals `"service"` (you can change the class checking using `starts-with()` or `contains()` if necessary).